# What is the threshold between high Aspect Ratios and low Aspect Ratios?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, glider

Oftentimes when describing flying organisms and vehicles, their wings are said to have a "high aspect ratio" or a "low aspect ratio". Sometimes the papers (that I read) gave the numbers, but more often, they would just leave the explanation at that.

So I was wondering, in general, what is the minimum ratio that would make it a "high AR" and what is the minimum ratio that would make it a "low AR"? Is there a threshold to be met, or is this analysis of AR rather relative and or subjective?

Answer (score 2):

The boundary depends on the type of aircraft. Fighter wings will be called high aspect ratio when the same aspect ratio in a glider wing will still be called low.

Generally, values below 5 are low, regardless of aircraft type.

With passenger aircraft, the boundary might be around 8.

Gliders will only have a high aspect ratio if it surpasses 20.

Still, there is no defined boundary and in the end the choice depends on the whims of the author.